# Salesforce LWC not working for File Upload

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, lwc

I am trying to use package to upload the file into s3 but it is not working as expected ,
I have tried multiple way's for it but i really can't find any solution,

HTML

```
<!-- FileUploaderLWC.html -->
<template>
  <div>
      <input type="file"  accept=".pdf,.png,.jpg" onchange={handleFileChange}></input>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

I have tried placing the debugger but it is not passing the package

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class DocumentManagementHome extends LightningElement {

  handleFileChange(event) {
    console.log('Hitted')
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        this.uploadFileToS3(file);
    }

    uploadFileToS3(file) {
        // Use AWS SDK to upload the file to S3 using the generated credentials
        // Here you'll need to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript, which can be imported via npm or included as a script tag
        // Initialize the AWS SDK with your credentials

        console.log('FILE',file)
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            accessKeyId: 'key',
            secretAccessKey: 'secret',
        });

        console.log(s3)

        const params = {
            Bucket: 'bucketName',
            Key: file.name,
            Body: file
        };

        s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
          console.log('Called')
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error uploading file: ', err);
            } else {
                console.log('123')
                console.log('File uploaded successfully: ', data.Location);
            }
        });
    }
}
```